# CMake can't find freeglut-3.0.0

Tags: windows, cmake, freeglut

Freeglut-3.0.0 is build with cmake (MinGW makefiles) and mingw and then successfully installed with `mingw32-make install` to `C:/Program Files (x86)/freeglut`.

My `CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

    project(math_tests)

    set(TESTS_SOURCES tests.cpp gl_core_3_3.c)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

    # GLUT
    find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR})
    if(NOT GLUT_FOUND)
        message(ERROR "GLUT not found!")
    endif(NOT GLUT_FOUND)

    # OpenGL
    find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${OpenGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${OpenGL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
    add_definitions(${OpenGL_DEFINITIONS})
    if(NOT OPENGL_FOUND)
        message(ERROR "OPENGL not found!")
    endif(NOT OPENGL_FOUND)

    add_executable(tests ${TESTS_SOURCES})
    target_link_libraries(tests math ${GLUT_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
```

Now CMake prints error: `Could NOT find GLUT (missing: GLUT_glut_LIBRARY).`

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your CMakeLists.txt file statement

```
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
```

is going to execute this code from FindGLUT.cmake

```
find_library( GLUT_glut_LIBRARY NAMES glut glut32 freeglut
    PATHS
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARY_DIR}
    ${GLUT_ROOT_PATH}/Release
    )
```

and `find_library` is in your scenario unable to find any of `glut glut32 freeglut` libraries, because it doesn't know where they are (which for you are under `C:/Program Files (x86)/freeglut`).

In your case you could set `${OPENGL_LIBRARY_DIR}` to the right directory, that is the one containing the freeglut.dll file, for e.g.:

```
set(OPENGL_LIBRARY_DIR "C:/Program Files (x86)/freeglut/lib")
```

given the file is under `C:/Program Files (x86)/freeglut/lib` directory.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. But how user will specify this path (since FindGLUT will require its variables instead of OPENG_LIBRARY_DIR in case it will not find GLUT)? Also, I'm building for Linux too, and CmakeLists.txt should work on both platforms. Currently it sets OPENGL_LIBRARY_DIR in `if (WIN32)` statement.

Comment: for multiplatform's sake, better to set [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH) to a the parent of ```"lib/<freeglutlibrary>"```, such as `"c:/program files (x86)/freeglut"` in your specific scenario. Best to avoid any specific  `SET` in your cmake, but let the end user set proper prefix with `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<your path>` at configuration time. Perhaps using OPTIONS to let enduser set a specific path to freeglut would be sensible too (and the option's value would be appended to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` by your script)

Comment: forgot to say that for Linux you do not need to set anything for the discovery of freeglut library, it should just work with no additional settings